# Where can I find a list of the LaTeX command line options?

Tags: compiling, latex-misc

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows, and am working with TeXnicCenter. I can see in the build profiles that LaTeX can take command-line options, for instance:

```
--src -interaction=nonstopmode
```

Try as I might, I cannot find anywhere on the net a list of these command line options and their purpose. Can anyone supply a link to these?

Comment: Try `latex --help` for a list of options and a short explanation.

Comment: [The official documentation](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/pdftex.html)

Comment: I edited the answer to include both comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most command line programs accept parameters like `--help` (originally from Unix) or `/?` (originally from Windows) that list their common options. `latex` (namely, `pdftex`, which is `latex` these days) is not an exception and recognizes `--help`. The same applies to other TeX engines like `xetex` or `luatex`.

On Unix, you can also type `man pdftex` etc. to read these programs' manual pages. MikTeX has them [online](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/pdftex.html); and TeX Live has the man pages in PDF format on your computer.

Modern TeX distributions (e.g. MiKTeX and TeX Live) have a `texdoc` command line tool. You can use

```
texdoc pdflatex
```

to get the document of `pdflatex`. Similarly, you can use `texdoc --help` or even `texdoc texdoc` to get help of the `texdoc` tool.